# using focus for a textfield

Tags: javascript, focus

I have two elements:

1. A texfield element, firstly hidden.
2. And a button element covering the textfield.

In other hand, I have one event called onDoubleClick which calls a function when a double click is made in the button. This function hides the button and show the textfield, **but I need that the textfield is editable in this moment** (like make a third click)

I read about focus() but it doesn't help me... http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_html_blur

How can I obtain it?

**EDIT**:

I'm obtaining well the input element:

```
var htmlElement = document.getElementById(this._tabsTitle[pos]._hPath);
var input = htmlElement[0];
input.focus();
```

The **htmlElement** var is a form, and the **input** var is the input field, I obtain it well, I'm looking with chrome inspector, with debugger, but focus() doesn't work...

**SOLUTION**

**It's was mine mistake...this code is part of a big project, and focus was working fine, but didn't make anything due to a thread problem** ... I checked it and solved it, and now it works like a charm :-) thanks to all

Regards, Daniel

Comment: show us the code you tried.?

Comment: may be [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mZGJN/1/) would help

Comment: Hi mithunsatheesh, I have been looking your link, but I can't hide the button element, I only can change its value to ""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mZGJN/9/). I believe it does what you want.

html

```
<input type="text" style="display:none" id="txtField1" />
<input type="button" id="btn1" value="Double Click Here" />
```

js

```
function modify() {
   //lets hide the button
   document.getElementById("btn1").style.display= "none";
   // show the text field
   document.getElementById("txtField1").style.display = "block"; 
   // now focus on the field
   document.getElementById("txtField1").focus();  
}

var el = document.getElementById("btn1");
// attaches event to the button
el.addEventListener("dblclick", modify, false);
```

**UPDATED according to comments on top(below question).**

if you dont want the button to be hidden and make its value null.

replace the line

```
document.getElementById("btn1").style.display= "none";
```

by

```
document.getElementById("btn1").value= "";
```

Comment: Yes, this answer is what I need, but I still don't obtain it...but is just what I need.

Comment: Hi dear, I'm with google chrome inspector...using debugger; I'm looking that I'm obtaining the input element properly...but I don't obtain it...I'm going to edit the post right now...please help me

Answer (score 2):

could this be a timing problem?

Please try this:

```
    onDoubleClick(function(){
       setTimeout(function(){
         button.focus();
       },50);
    });
```

Comment: @DanielGarciaSanchez : have you got your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue as you and finally find a way out by using callback function.
My code is:

```
                                            <s:textfield 
                                                id="clientUnitNoId" 
                                                name="clientUnitNumber" 
                                                value="%{clientUnitNumber}"
                                                size="20" maxlength="8" 
                                                onchange="validateClientUnit(this.value)" cssClass="inputTextField"/>

...
    if ( !isValid){
        Ext.MessageBox.alert('ERROR', 
        'The Client Unit# only allows Alphanumeric data ',
        function(){
            document.getElementById('clientUnitNoId').focus();
            document.getElementById('clientUnitNoId').select();} );
            return false;
        }
```